# Loading a Lot of Data into Google Bigquery from Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I've been struggling to load big chunks of data into bigquery for a little while now. In Google's docs, I see the [insertAll](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/bigquery_v2.tabledata.html#insertAll) method, which seems to work fine, but gives me 413 "Entity too large" errors when I try to send anything over about 100k of data in JSON. [Per Google's docs, I should be able to send up to 1TB of uncompressed data in JSON](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery). What gives? The example on the previous page has me building the request body manually instead of using insertAll, which is uglier and more error prone. I'm also not sure what format the data should be in in that case.

So, all of that said, what is the clean/proper way of loading lots of data into Bigquery? An example with data would be great. If at all possible, I'd really rather not build the request body myself.

Comment: What is the format of your source data?

Comment: @Rohit it shouldn't matter. Just data I'm inserting into bigquery. Inserting any data should be fine for example's sake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that for streaming data to BQ, [anything above 10k rows/sec](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#quota) requires talking to a sales rep.

If you'd like to send large chunks directly to BQ, you can [send it via `POST`](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery#loaddatapostrequest). If you're using a client library, it should handle making the upload resumable for you. To do this, you'll need to make a call to [`jobs.insert()`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/bigquery_v2.jobs.html#insert) instead of `tabledata.insertAll()`, and provide a description of a [`load` job](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery#loaddatapostrequest). To actually push the bytes using the Python client, you can create a [`MediaFileUpload`](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/googleapiclient/http.py#L381) or [`MediaInMemoryUpload`](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/googleapiclient/http.py#L444) and pass it as the `media_body` parameter.

The other option is to stage the data in Google Cloud Storage and [load it from there](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery#loaddatagcs).

Comment: I don't want to stream the data. I'd ideally load it in a couple of chunks. Is there no way to do this outside of using Cloud Storage? My company currently doesn't use Cloud Storage for anything and it seems like a completely extra and unnecessary step to first load it there.

Comment: Sure -- you can send it directly via `POST`. If you've already got files sitting somewhere, though, `gsutil` makes this pretty easy (they handle things like parallel upload without any work on your part).

Comment: I do have a client library. I'm using Python for this, but as far as I can tell, insertAll is the only way to do this. I'm looking at https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/. This is where the initial question came from.

Comment: You can also call [`jobs.insert()`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/bigquery_v2.jobs.html#insert) with a `load` job, and pass the `media_body` parameter with either a [`MediaFileUpload`](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/googleapiclient/http.py#L381) or [`MediaInMemoryUpload`](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/googleapiclient/http.py#L444).

Comment: Just a follow up: Craig's answer is correct, but all of this stuff is really poorly documented. If anyone from Google is listening, it says almost nowhere that `insertAll()` is only for streaming, and why there are no examples of `jobs.insert()` for loading data, especially on https://developers.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery#loaddatapostrequest is beyond me. I spent way longer than necessary on what should have been a simple task because of piss-poor documentation, and this does not make me want to continue to use BigQuery.

Comment: MediaInMemoryUpload says "deprecated - now use MediaIoBaseUpload"

Answer (score 1):

The example [here](https://code.google.com/p/bigquery-e2e/source/browse/samples/ch06/load_resumable.py) uses the resumable upload to upload a CSV file. While the file used is small, it should work for virtually any size upload since it uses a robust media upload protocol. It sounds like you want json, which means you'd need to tweak the code slightly for json (an example for json is in the load_json.py example in the same directory). If you have a stream you want to upload instead of a file, you can use a [MediaInMemoryUpload](https://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/apiclient.http.MediaInMemoryUpload-class.html) instead of the [MediaFileUpload](https://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/apiclient.http.MediaFileUpload-class.html) that is used in the example.

BTW ... Craig's answer is correct, I just thought I'd chime in with links to sample code.

Comment: That example seems to have been moved. Can you update your answer please.

Comment: Media links both broken and MediaInMemoryUpload says deprecated