# Insert large amount of data to BigQuery via bigquery-python library

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-bigquery, large-data

I have large csv files and excel files where I read them and create the needed create table script dynamically depending on the fields and types it has. Then insert the data to the created table.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23770799/loading-a-lot-of-data-into-google-bigquery-from-python) and understood that I should send them with `jobs.insert()` instead of `tabledata.insertAll()` for large amount of data.

This is how I call it (Works for smaller files not large ones).

```
result  = client.push_rows(datasetname,table_name,insertObject) # insertObject is a list of dictionaries
```

When I use library's [push_rows](https://github.com/tylertreat/BigQuery-Python/blob/master/bigquery/client.py#L1209) it gives this error in windows.

```
[Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

and this in ubuntu.

```
[Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

So when I went through [BigQuery-Python](https://github.com/tylertreat/BigQuery-Python/blob/master/bigquery/client.py#L1264) code it uses `table_data.insertAll()`.

How can I do this with this library? I know we can upload through Google storage but I need direct upload method with this.

Answer (score 4):

When handling large files don't use streaming, but batch load: Streaming will easily handle up to 100,000 rows per second. That's pretty good for streaming, but not for loading large files.

The sample code linked is doing the right thing (batch instead of streaming), so what we see is a different problem: This sample code is trying to load all this data straight into BigQuery, but the uploading through POST part fails. `gsutil` has a more robust uploading algorithm than just a plain POST.

Solution: Instead of loading big chunks of data through POST, stage them in Google Cloud Storage first, then tell BigQuery to read files from GCS.

See also [BigQuery script failing for large file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39101602/132438)

Comment: Did you just add a link to the OP?!

Comment: oops, fixing recursion !

Comment: @FelipeHoffa gsutil can I use inside python code? There was some column types issues when directly give the csv file path and upload. so I can read the csv and cast the fields accordingly. Isnt there a way to insert the object (may be a list of dictionaries) to the table after I cast them?