# BigQuery script failing for large file

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery

I am trying to load a json file to **GoogleBigquery** using the script at 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/api/load_data_by_post.py with very little modification.
I added

```
,chunksize=10*1024*1024, resumable=True))
```

to **MediaFileUpload**.

The script works fine for a sample file with a few million records. The actual file is about 140 GB with approx 200,000,000 records. **insert_request.execute()** always fails with

```
socket.error: `[Errno 32] Broken pipe`
```

after half an hour or so. How can this be fixed? Each row is less than 1 KB, so it shouldn't be a quota issue.

Comment: same question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971523/insert-large-amount-of-data-to-bigquery-via-bigquery-python-library

Comment: Fixed formatting and typos

Comment: Hey Jayadevan, I'm in the BigQuery engineering team, and if you would like to post the project and job id, I could take a look and see if anything stands out in our logs.

Answer (score 2):

When handling large files don't use streaming, but batch load: Streaming will easily handle up to 100,000 rows per second. That's pretty good for streaming, but not for loading large files.

The sample code linked is doing the right thing (batch instead of streaming), so what we see is a different problem: This sample code is trying to load all this data straight into BigQuery, but the uploading through POST part fails.

Solution: Instead of loading big chunks of data through POST, stage them in Google Cloud Storage first, then tell BigQuery to read files from GCS.

*Update*: Talking to the engineering team, POST should work if you try a smaller `chunksize`.

Comment: Some observations, in case it helps someone . I don't think chunksize is the issue. When I was pilot-testing earlier with just 10 million records, I kept it at 100 MB and it worked. With the new, full data file, I was getting the error mentioned above. Then I switched to compressed format and ran into quota issue. Then I split the compressed file into chunks and it is working, but taking a lot of time. The next step is to split the uncompressed file into chunks and try that. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: @Jayadevan I also have same type of issue. For me 8.5mb csv it takes lot of time kind of stuck at this line. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/api/load_data_by_post.py#L80 Any idea? Do you have  a reference url for your working code?

Comment: Did you use chunk_size? I now have the mediafileupload in a try/except block so that one more attempt is made. Checking for the error condition and having a specific exception clause is better. This is how I have the code now             try:
                                                job = insert_request.execute()
                                          except:
                                                job = insert_request.execute()
You said "stuck". Are you getting an error or it is sort of hung?