# BQ insert_rows ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have a problem with BigQuery `insert_rows` command

`client.insert_rows(bq_table, chunk, ignore_unknown_values=True)`

I respect avery limitations about contents lenght, but very often the upload command is not executed correctly. Error:

`('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))`

Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Is the project location local to you?  Long distance far regions can cause disconnects?

Comment: Yes, it's in europe

Comment: Might also find gsutil more robust - per this article : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971523/insert-large-amount-of-data-to-bigquery-via-bigquery-python-library   -   another handy reference https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migration-to-google-cloud-transferring-your-large-datasets